# commit from worktree changes remote url in .git/config

Tags: git, git-worktree

when i try to commit from a worktree, the repo config file
is changed to an incorrect remote url.
when i am committing from the main worktree it is changed back to the correct one.

from my repo in master branch i create a worktree by:

```
/path/to/my/master$ git worktree add ../branch_x -b feature/branch_x
```

when i have a commit ready

```
path/to/my/branch_x$ git add .
path/to/my/branch_x$ git commit -m "some message"
```

then in the /path/to/my/master/.git/config file

```
[remote "origin"]
        url = ssh://path_to_bitbucket:7999/bitbucket/proj/master.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
        pushurl = git@path_to_bitbucket/master.git
```

is changed to

```
[remote "origin"]
        url = ssh://path_to_bitbucket:7999/bitbucket/proj/branch_x.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
        pushurl = git@path_to_bitbucket/branch_x.git
```

and then all work with remote fails...

Comment: Are you using a hook like `post-commit` which may rewrite the `remote.origin.url`?

Comment: 10X, it seems to be a pre-commit hook that does that.

Comment: “it seems to be a pre-commit hook that does that.” So update the question.